# getting SSL erorr while connecting to second-level subdomain using AWS load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am using AWS load balancer to listen to *dev.example.com* and *api.dev.example.com*. I have added amazon managed certificates in the listener for both the subdomains. I can connect to *dev.example.com* successfully, but for *api.dev.example.com* I am getting an SSL error. I am using AWS default security policy(ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08). I did sslscan for api.dev subdomain and got the following error

```
  TLS Fallback SCSV:
Connection failed - unable to determine TLS Fallback SCSV support

  TLS renegotiation:
Session renegotiation not supported

  TLS Compression:
OpenSSL version does not support compression
Rebuild with zlib1g-dev package for zlib support

  Heartbleed:

  Supported Server Cipher(s):
    Unable to parse certificate
    Unable to parse certificate
    Unable to parse certificate
    Unable to parse certificate
Certificate information cannot be retrieved.
```

Why is sslscan failing for *api.dev* subdomain while it is successful for *dev* subdomain? How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second level subdomains have to be listed in the SSL certificate. If you have a `*.example.com` wildcard certificate the wildcard is only valid for one level. You would also need to add wildcards for other levels, like: `*.dev.example.com`.

This is not a limitation of AWS, it is a limitation of SSL certificates.

Comment: Yes, that was my first thought. I added an AWS managed certificate with domains `dev.example.com`, `*.example.com` and  `*.dev.example.com`. I am still getting the same error. It is working for api.example.com but not for api.dev.example.com

Comment: When you open https://api.dev.example.com in your web browser do you get an SSL certificate error? If you do not, then this is a bug with the testing tool you are using. If you do, then you didn't add the certificate correctly.

Comment: Yes, it was a certificate issue in the DNS server. Certificates were not added for the second-level subdomains.